# Подвисание Teamcity при запуске

Tags: teamcity, allure

После установки плагина allure, некоторой смены конфигурации и плановой перезагрузки teamcity стал подвисать при запуске на этой строчке:

```
teamcity_1       | Log4J configuration file /opt/TeamCity/bin/../conf/teamcity-server-log4j.xml will be monitored with interval 10 seconds.
```

Есть ли идеи, как сохранить конфигурацию и вернуть его в рабочее состояние?

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Какая версия Тимсити, какая версия аллюра? Попробуй убрать AllureBuildStep, исправит ли это проблему

Comment: @DmitryBaev боюсь, той конфигурации уже нет, я пробовал найти лучшее решение под конкретный кейс, тогда в результате остановились на дженкинсе. Хотел сказать спасибо, что не забрасываете проект!